# cascade = CascadeType.ALL what to expect?

Tags: java, hibernate, tapestry

I'm wondering what to expect when I use cascade = CascadeType.ALL as such,

```
@OneToMany(
         mappedBy = "employeeProfile",
         cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
         orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ProfileEffortAllocation> effortAllocations;

public List<ProfileEffortAllocation> getEffortAllocations() {
    if (effortAllocations == null) {
        effortAllocations = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return effortAllocations;
}

public void setEffortAllocations(List<ProfileEffortAllocation> effortAllocations) {
    this.effortAllocations = effortAllocations;
}
```

I'm finding when I add a new effortAllocation and attempt to save object, but have a validation failure preventing my code from ever reaching `session.saveOrUpdate(parentObj)`, I'm still getting a pk rather than null as if persist is being called on the child `OneToMany`. Should my parent object call `session.saveOrUpdate(parentObj);` before I ever see a pk from effortAllocation?

I'd like to point out that the parent object is an existing object and has been loaded from the database with a pk prior to adding a new child record.

Comment: Can you post that error ?

Comment: @Jay there is no error/exception, I'm just getting a pk for my child objects before I ever saveOrUpdate the parent object. This is a problem when a form validation error occurs and I have to reload the page with the validation error before I have ran the saveOrUpdate method for the parent object. Once the page reloads, the child objects now have pk id's although they have yet to be saved to the database. Every save with a validation error increments the unsaved child object pk id.

Comment: @Jay, should the child objects only be persisted when the parent object is saved? I'm not sure how a child object could get it's id before the parent has been saved. I'm not calling saveOrUpdate any wheres else in the code. Only for the parent object at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `CascadeType.ALL`, whenever you do any operation on the parent all those operations would also get cascaded to the child.

Yes you should call saveOrUpdate(parent)

In your case as the parent objects are already existing. You could load the existing parent and create a new child and attach the child to parent and when you call saveOrUpdate(parent), it should update the parent and create all those child and relate it to that parent.

Yes it is generating a id for child, because it is trying to create a child due to cascade all and you could have configured it to generate id in @Id.

Enable sql logs using `hibernate.show_sql` to understand better whats happening.

I assume you would have a `@JoinColumn` in your child which would map to the parent primary key.

Comment: So I turned query logging on to find an insert happening, I think removed other table queries to find it eventually went away. At this point in time I'm unsure why a query during a save would cause an insert before the saveOrUpdate is ever called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was do to a lookup query triggering a flush prior to returning it's results. The solution was to set `this.session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);`

Hibernate tries to ensure that database conents is up-to-date before making any queries.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2316849